# Preset NSUserDefaults

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I thought I read some where that I could include a NSUserDefaults file with a cocoa app. I cannot seem to find how to do that.

I know I could just create on first app launch but I dont want to do that just yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [User Defaults Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/NSUserDefaultsController.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001092-164973) doc is your friend. You'll want to `-registerDefaults:`, which is going to be an `NSDictionary` instance created at runtime or loaded from a plist file in your app's resources folder.

As to not wanting to do it just yet, when did you plan to? If you're going to register your app's defaults at all, it's to be done at every launch.

Comment: "loaded from a plist file in your app's resources folder." That is what I was looking for. I will have to lookup how to make an NSDictionary from a plist. Thanks!